# Always being logged in as SA and not Windows account

Tags: sql-server, schema, authentication

First off i would like to appologise if i sound stupid as i do not have much knowladge of SQL Server.

I have recently started a project working with SQL Server 2008 R2. I have access to the database using Windows Authentication. Once logged in i can access all of the databases etc... My problem is, for my user DOMAIN/Glen i would like to add a default schema for one of the databases. I have changed the Default schema for 'DOMAIN\Glen' within the users section under the database in question however whenever i run a script without the schema prefix on the table it will not run.

I have been looking around and trying some things out and to my knowladge i am for some reason using the SA account and not the DOMAIN\Glen login.

If anyone could help me change my Loged in user from SA to DOMAIN\Glen that would be a great help.

Thanks

Boldonglen

---

EDIT

When i am accessing the database directly on the server it is logging me in as DOMAIN\Glen but when i am accessing it from my computer it is logging me in as SA.

---

EDIT 2

Also when i connect to SQL Server on the server normally i am getting the default schema of the one i have added however if i run SQL server on the server as an administrator i am getting the default schema of dbo.

---

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DEFAULT_SCHEMA` is ignored if the user is a member of the `sysadmin` fixed role. If `DOMAIN\Glen` is in the `sysadmin` role, the default schema is always `dbo` and you have to explicitly use the schema name.